# how to pass a multi line json string in map in argo workflows

Tags: json, loops, argo-workflows, multilinestring

I am working on creating a argo workflow with a loop `withParam` for map variable. In this map I want to use multi line json string. Is there any way to use it?

Here is the way am using `policy` as multi line string but it is not working

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: loops-param-arg-
spec:
  entrypoint: loop-param-arg-example
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: os-list
      value: |
        [
          { "image": "debian", "tag": "9.1", "policy": "{
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                  {
                      "Sid": "BucketAdmin",
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": "*",
                      "Action": "s3:*",
                      "Resource": "*"
                  }
              ]
          }" },
          { "image": "ubuntu", "tag": "17.10", "policy":  "{
              "Version": "2012-10-17",
              "Statement": [
                  {
                      "Sid": "BucketAdmin",
                      "Effect": "Allow",
                      "Principal": "*",
                      "Action": "s3:*",
                      "Resource": "*"
                  }
              ]
          }"}
        ]
  templates:
  - name: loop-param-arg-example
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: os-list
    steps:
    - - name: test-linux
        template: cat-os-release
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: image
            value: "{{item.image}}"
          - name: tag
            value: "{{item.tag}}"
        withParam: "{{inputs.parameters.os-list}}"

  - name: cat-os-release
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: image
      - name: tag
    container:
      image: "{{inputs.parameters.image}}:{{inputs.parameters.tag}} and policy is {{inputs.parameters.policy}}"
      command: [cat]
      args: [/etc/os-release]
```

Is there any way in argo workflows to achieve this? if not, what's the alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions provided by Michael works and also the below solution works for you with some readability of the policy

```
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: loops-param-arg-
spec:
  entrypoint: loop-param-arg-example
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: os-list
      value: |
        [
          { "image": "debian", "tag": "9.1", "policy": {
                                                          "Version": "2012-10-17",
                                                          "Statement": [
                                                              {
                                                                  "Sid": "BucketAdmin",
                                                                  "Effect": "Allow",
                                                                  "Principal": "*",
                                                                  "Action": "s3:*",
                                                                  "Resource": "*"
                                                              }
                                                          ]
                                                      } },
          { "image": "ubuntu", "tag": "17.10", "policy":  {
                                                            "Version": "2012-10-17",
                                                            "Statement": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "Sid": "BucketAdmin",
                                                                    "Effect": "Allow",
                                                                    "Principal": "*",
                                                                    "Action": "s3:*",
                                                                    "Resource": "*"
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
          }
        ]
  templates:
  - name: loop-param-arg-example
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: os-list
    steps:
    - - name: test-linux
        template: cat-os-release
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: image
            value: "{{item.image}}"
          - name: tag
            value: "{{item.tag}}"
        withParam: "{{inputs.parameters.os-list}}"

  - name: cat-os-release
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: image
      - name: tag
    container:
      image: "{{inputs.parameters.image}}:{{inputs.parameters.tag}} and policy is {{inputs.parameters.policy}}"
      command: [cat]
      args: [/etc/os-release]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are three issues:

1. The policies are not valid JSON. The asterisks must be quoted since they are strings.

   ```
     {
       "Sid": "BucketAdmin",
       "Effect": "Allow",
   -   "Principal": *,
   +   "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:*",
   -   "Resource": *
   +   "Resource": "*"
     }
   ```
2. (**UPDATE**: this change isn't actually necessary - Argo Workflows properly handles the `policy` JSON object.) The policies should be encoded as strings so they can be passed easily as parameters. For example:

   ```json
   "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"BucketAdmin\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:*\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}"
   ```
3. The policy value needs to be explicitly passed as a parameter to the cat-os-release template.

The final working workflow should look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: loops-param-arg-
spec:
  entrypoint: loop-param-arg-example
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: os-list
        value: |
          [
            {
              "image": "debian",
              "tag": "9.1",
              "policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"BucketAdmin\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:*\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}"
            },
            {
              "image": "ubuntu",
              "tag": "17.10",
              "policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"BucketAdmin\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:*\",\"Resource\":\"*\"}]}"
            }
          ]
  templates:
    - name: loop-param-arg-example
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: os-list
      steps:
        - - name: test-linux
            template: cat-os-release
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: image
                  value: "{{item.image}}"
                - name: tag
                  value: "{{item.tag}}"
                - name: policy
                  value: "{{item.policy}}"
            withParam: "{{inputs.parameters.os-list}}"

    - name: cat-os-release
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: image
          - name: tag
          - name: policy
      container:
        image: "{{inputs.parameters.image}}:{{inputs.parameters.tag}}"
        command: [echo]
        args: ["{{inputs.parameters.policy}}"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @michael crenshaw, it is working. But I have big policies, if I add escape characters for every instruction in the policy we are missing readability of the policy.

Comment: I've made the changes in the question. Added double quotes for asterisks

Comment: @monu interesting, didn't know you could have a non-string `item.something` member. Will update my answer!